# Saving processor time on running command

Tags: performance-tuning

How to run only the last line of code rather than the default option in .m file to 'Run all code'?

Comment: Why don't you use notebooks will separate cells instead of `.m` files?  Cells can be emulated in .m files too, if you open them with Mathematica itself (not a text editor). Use the Divide Cell command in the Cell menu.

Comment: @Szabolcs: I am sorry for not reading, but am unable to run command from notebook, seem lost in that.

Comment: I suggest you start here, everything is explained in detail: https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/2nd-ed/  If that's too basic, then here: https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-programmers/en/

Comment: @Szabolcs: I am unable to find info. regarding running commands in notebook in the basic one. I tried to search by giving query which led me to :http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/WolframSystemSessions.html. But, this also not points towards that.

Comment: @Alucard: That combination leads to what? I see no effect.

Comment: damn i mean shift-enter

Comment: @Alucard: Nothing happened. But, on shift + enter, there was a display of list with 5 digits from 1..5.

Comment: @jiten yes i meant shift-enter, i forgot my keyboard has a different structure

Comment: @Alucard: Thanks for that, it worked for running a single command. But, if I have to get such basic information in toto, then please tell any specific source/book. Also, in particular please tell the source for this information.

Comment: @jiten https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/UsingANotebookInterface.html

Comment: @Alucard: Sorry for asking. But, you have given a very broad reference. Can you give me the keyword to search for. Else, tell me the subsection in which to search.

Comment: Everything you need to get started with Mathematica is explained in that book, including the Shift-Enter shortcut. Just start reading *from the beginning* (Preface) and go through at least the first 9 chapters before you ask your next question.